# Visual Studio - Making a table row clickable using JQuery Server Side

Tags: jquery, html, vb.net

I am trying to get some help on how i can make the below table rows clickable using a JQuery function. I have tried using the usual onClick or.click within a function but nothing happens no mater what part of the table i am calling. The table is placed within a   so i am finding it difficult to make all individual rows clickable.

If i was creating the table the usual HMTL way i'm sure that i would be able to accomplish this but i need your help.

My .aspx code...

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/UserMast.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ViewDuplicateNames.aspx.vb" Inherits="ViewDuplicateNames" %>
```

```
    <p id="duplicatePara">Users with the same combination</p>

<div id="vTable">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="duplicateResults" runat="server" ></asp:PlaceHolder>
</div>
```

My aspx.vb code...

```
Protected Sub buttonSearch_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles buttonSearch.Click

    Dim dsResults As New DataSet
    Dim dt As DataTableReader


    dsResults = SearchResults(sLog.Value.ToString, sfirstName.Value.ToString, slastName.Value.ToString, sNumber.Value.ToString, sVal.Value.ToString)
    dt = dsResults.CreateDataReader


    Dim tb As New Table
    Dim tr As New TableRow
    Dim tc As New TableCell
    Dim lb As New Label
    Dim iCount As Integer = 1



    tb.CssClass = "tableStyle"
    tb.CellPadding =
    tb.CellSpacing = 0


    If dt.HasRows = True Then

        tr = New TableRow
        tr.CssClass = "tabHeader"
        tc = New TableCell
        lb = New Label

        lb.Text = "Log"
        tc.Controls.Add(lb)
        tr.Controls.Add(tc)

        tb.Controls.Add(tr)


        tr.CssClass = "tabHeader"
        tc = New TableCell
        lb = New Label

        lb.Text = "Staff"
        tc.Controls.Add(lb)
        tr.Controls.Add(tc)

        tb.Controls.Add(tr)

        tr.CssClass = "tabHeader"
        tc = New TableCell
        lb = New Label

        lb.Text = "Family Name"
        tc.Controls.Add(lb)
        tr.Controls.Add(tc)

        tb.Controls.Add(tr)


        tr.CssClass = "tabHeader"
        tc = New TableCell
        lb = New Label

        lb.Text = "First name"
        tc.Controls.Add(lb)
        tr.Controls.Add(tc)

        tb.Controls.Add(tr)


        tr.CssClass = "tabHeader"
        tc = New TableCell
        lb = New Label

        lb.Text = "Middlename"
        tc.Controls.Add(lb)
        tr.Controls.Add(tc)

        tb.Controls.Add(tr)

        tr.CssClass = "tabHeader"
        tc = New TableCell
        lb = New Label

        lb.Text = "DOB"
        tc.Controls.Add(lb)
        tr.Controls.Add(tc)

        tb.Controls.Add(tr)

        tr.CssClass = "tabHeader"
        tc = New TableCell
        lb = New Label

        lb.Text = "Number"
        tc.Controls.Add(lb)
        tr.Controls.Add(tc)

        tb.Controls.Add(tr)

        tr.CssClass = "tabHeader"
        tc = New TableCell
        lb = New Label

        lb.Text = "Job"
        tc.Controls.Add(lb)
        tr.Controls.Add(tc)

        tb.Controls.Add(tr)

        tr.CssClass = "tabHeader"
        tc = New TableCell
        lb = New Label

        lb.Text = "Loc"
        tc.Controls.Add(lb)
        tr.Controls.Add(tc)

        tb.Controls.Add(tr)

        tr.CssClass = "tabHeader"
        tc = New TableCell
        lb = New Label

        lb.Text = "Site"
        tc.Controls.Add(lb)
        tr.Controls.Add(tc)

        tb.Controls.Add(tr)

        tr.CssClass = "tabHeader"
        tc = New TableCell
        lb = New Label

        lb.Text = "Comments"
        tc.Controls.Add(lb)
        tr.Controls.Add(tc)

        tb.Controls.Add(tr)

        Do While dt.Read


            tr = New TableRow

            If iCount = 1 Then
                tr.CssClass = "rowStyle1"
                iCount = 0
            Else
                tr.CssClass = "rowStyle2"
                iCount = 1
            End If



            tc = New TableCell
            tc.CssClass = "rowCell"
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("log").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)
            tb.Controls.Add(tr)


            'tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.CssClass = "rowCell"
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("staff").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)
            tb.Controls.Add(tr)


            ' tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.CssClass = "rowCell"
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("surname").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)
            tb.Controls.Add(tr)


            'tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.CssClass = "rowCell"
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("forename").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)
            tb.Controls.Add(tr)


            'tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.CssClass = "rowCell"
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("middlename").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)
            tb.Controls.Add(tr)


            'tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.CssClass = "rowCell"
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("dob").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)
            tb.Controls.Add(tr)

            'tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.CssClass = "rowCell"
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("num").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)
            tb.Controls.Add(tr)

            'tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.CssClass = "rowCell"
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("pos").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)
            tb.Controls.Add(tr)

            'tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.CssClass = "rowCell"
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("loc").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)
            tb.Controls.Add(tr)

            'tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.CssClass = "rowCell"
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("site").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)
            tb.Controls.Add(tr)

            'tr = New TableRow
            tc = New TableCell
            tc.CssClass = "rowCell"
            lb = New Label

            lb.Text = dt.Item("comments").ToString()
            tc.Controls.Add(lb)
            tr.Controls.Add(tc)
            tb.Controls.Add(tr)

        Loop
        dt.Close()
        dsResults.Dispose()

        placeResults.Controls.Add(tb)

    Else

        noResultOutput.Text = "No User Account Located"

    End If


End Sub
```

I apologize it is very long.

If i have missed anything that will help you please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Why are you building your output (HTML) in code-behind?

Comment: apologies for the delay in responding. This is the way i have been asked to build it, i would of built it differently so it would be easier to change/modify but this is the way i have to do it.

Comment: Well that may be the case, but clicking and/or selecting the row and thus enabling buttons is a clientside matter; or at least it should be. You *could* use some kind of postback mechanism on selecting the row and rebuilding the table with the selected row etcetera, but I would not recommend it. Let me emphasize that: big no-no there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make each row clickable and to show an alert. I have not been able to find a solution on how to show hidden buttons once clicked but i think this can be done with the JQuery Accordian?

My solution to make the rows clickable;

```
tr = New TableRow

            tr.Attributes.Add("onClick", "testMe('" & dt.Item("sLog").ToString & "')")
```

Then on the HTML side;

```
<script>
function testMe(myLogin) {

    alert(myLogin);
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is to set ClientID on each TableRow.

```
tr = New TableRow
tr.ClientID = "tableRowID"
```

Then on the ASP page, add attribute to set static ClientIdMode

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/UserMast.master" .... ClientIDMode="Static" %>
```

Now you should be able to use the ID of each row with jQuery for click event.

```
$('#tableRowID').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        if(href) {
            window.location = href;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have tried adding the tr.ClientID = "tableRowID" live but it keeps telling me 'property 'ClientID' is readonly'. Any suggestions?